# IntelliJ Redoing Git Merge On Select File

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, undo

I'm in the middle of a big merge that I do in IntelliJ. After an hour of struggle I could somehow merge some of the files, then accidentally closed the file I was just merging. Thus saving it. In a bad form. I wanted to resume the merging of that file, but the file's name disappeared from the list of conflicting files.

How can I remerge that one file again without reverting all my changes to start over? Redoing all the merges from the beginning is not an option, because actually already did a revert because of this very same accident for which I don't have a Ctrl-Z.

I tried reverting the file, but the file still doesn't show up between the conflicting files, so I cannot resume that three-pane merge-window. Or can I in a different way?

Comment: `but the file's name disappeared from the list of conflicting files.`. That doesn't sound right to me.  If you messed around in that file, perhaps by removing some conflict markers and/or making other changes, then the file should still show up as conflicted.  The conflict doesn't "officially" end until you `git add` the file, and tell Git that the conflict has been resolved.

Comment: Well it doesn't sound right to me either, but this is how IntelliJ does. Currently I'm on trying a separate merge tool P4, or something that might work as I would request.

Comment: IntelliJ has nothing to with this really; it's just a text editor after all.  Are you saying that your typed `git status` right after the merge and the file showed up, but then after closing that file in IntelliJ, `git status` does _not_ still show that file in conflict?

Comment: What you said seems to be a good lead. Before I posted my question, reverted the file so it now contains those <<<<<<<, =======, >>>>>>> symbols. Now I tried `git status` and sees the file as changed, not as in conflict. Is there I way, I can make git seeing that file to be in conflict, not simply as changed? Anyway, I'll search for this solution.

Comment: Try `git reset -- <filePath>`